# Renaming the term "Employee" in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I need to rename the term "Employee" to another word in NetSuite.

Unfortunately, the "Rename Records/Transactions" functional doesn't support Employee record.

I know how to rename "Employee" for employee menu item (Lists -> List Overview -> Set Up Custom Tab) and on the record forms (beforeLoad user events), but I have no idea how to do it for List Page "Employees".

[image]
If you have any idea or any suggestions I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I have found the following way of solution to the problem: It is possible to add a new column in the search view, which has type of "Formula". and set a script-injection, which modifies HTML elements, as value this formula.